# Android searchable tab activity

Tags: android, tabactivity, searchable

I have a TabActivity that has multiple tabs, each a separate activity. One of them is defined as searchable in the manifest. There is always only one instance of the TabActivity and any of the tabs, therefore this tab activity has singleTop as launchmode. However, instead of returning to the tab search opens a new naked instance of the activity.

```
    <activity android:name=".tab1Activity" android:label="tab1" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

Being new to android I am probably missing something obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully - are you instigating a 'search' from outside of your app (i.e., can other apps use your search activity) or is the search instigated from one of your other tab activities?

Comment: Inside using the search button. I want it to return to the activity where I can read the search query from a new intent. Instead it opens a new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" 
    android:resource="@xml/search" />
```

Change your intent filter, try this code. I can't see any difference except category line.

Comment: No difference. Using Android 2.2. :/